# PhD Qualification on a CV: Should I list it as ongoing in a separate section?

Tags: phd, postdocs

I'm just finishing my PhD but don't yet have the qualification.

I'm applying for a post-doc and need to construct a CV.

Should I include my PhD as "ongoing" in a separate section to the rest of my education? Or can I just indicate it as part of my education, but with a note like "2011-present" or something?

Comment: you can add your expected graduation time, to clarify when you will be available for the next job.

Comment: Expected graduation 2016

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I include my PhD as "ongoing" in a separate section to the rest of my education? Or can I just indicate it as part of my education, but with a note like "2011-present" or something?

The second option. I.e., just indicate it as part of the education while noting explicitly something like 
*"2011- 2016 (expected)"*

Answer (score 3):

Building on the above answer, to be completely clear, you should also consider stating your status explicitly afterwards, like so:

2011-2016 (expected) PhD/doctoral candidate, Name of University
Thesis Title: "XXX"

"Doctoral candidate" would be a further acceptable alternative to "PhD candidate" and some people add the name of their doctoral supervisor, especially if the application is for a faculty/research position and it's someone in your field who might be known to the committee.